# How do you enable ssl debugging for a keycloak container?

Tags: java, ssl, keycloak

I'm trying to hook Keycloak up to an external openLDAP using mutual authentication ssl.  I'm having problems figuring this out because the error codes from Keycloak are very terse.
I know ssl debuging can be turned on by passing -Djavax.net.debug=ssl to Keycloak.  But I'm running Keycloak in a prebuilt container and passing it in with -e doesn't seem to do anything.  Is their an easy method to do this?
This is on Keycloak 8.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this was a user error issue.
This can be passed in several ways.

The following works

`-e JAVA_OPTS=-Djavax.net.debug=ssl`

Putting the following in the Dockerfile works

`ENV JAVA_OPTS=-Djavax.net.debug=ssl`

and of course you can change standalone.conf and have your Dockerfile copy it into the image over the original.